# PHP development environment

Tags: php, codeigniter, development-environment

I normally work on Python projects and we have a good tool called virtualenv for setting up project environments. Does something similar exist for PHP? I have not been able to find one.

Comment: Can you tell us what virtualenv does? "Setting up project environments" is quite vague.

Comment: Sure, you run it on your project folder and it setups a local project bin and lib dir. Combined with easy_install (The python installer) you can then pull in any libs you've specified as dependencies in your setup.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) does what you want. PEAR is a repository of various useful classes. You can download them, but you also use the [Command Line to manage packages](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php). Apart from this, there is nothing I know that would do this. There is [phing to automate build processes](http://phing.info/). It's like Java's Ant. And some frameworks have RAD tools to setup projects, but those are usually aimed at the framework specific parts.

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking at PEAR but its not 100% clear to me how I can have a per project include path. I'll look into that some more. I certainly think the tool I'm looking for should use PEAR.

Comment: @dcolish you can set the [include path at runtime](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) or do you mean you want have all the libs you download from PEAR for the application in the application folder?

Comment: I meant the latter. I'd like to have the project specific libs be part of the project only. I do not want to have them available system wide. This way I can possibly pin versions of libs based on a projects needs.

Comment: @dcolish I am not sure the pear manager can install in specific directories. You might have more luck with Phing then. Or maybe Zend_Tool from the Zend Framework. That's an extensible command line tool.

Comment: @Gordon I did some more digging and I think PEAR/Pyrus will do exactly what I need. I can set the include_path in a variety of config files specifically for that project. I don't think it will be hard to script this out.

Comment: @dcolish Cool. Didnt now Pyrus. Will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

[eclipse helios for php developers](http://www.eclipse.org/helios/)

Comment: Not quite what I'm talking about here. I use emacs anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't really a way of doing this in PHP without having to install loads of tools. My best guess would be to set up a VCS, such as Git, and use branches to mimic environments. It's ugly, but it works.